# How to create a CastPlayer from ExoPlayer Cast extension?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I already have `ExoPlayer 2.7.2` running in my app. I want to add Cast functionality to it. How do I change my vanilla `ExoPlayer` to a `CastPlayer` using the ExoPlayer Cast extension?

Comment: Hi @khateeb, did you see these links? https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/new-cast-extension-and-demo-app-55816a50012 https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate

Comment: @khateeb, I have to do the same. Did you implement it? do you have any resource I can follow

Comment: @AkhilaMadari I followed the steps given in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [demo app for cast in the ExoPlayer repository](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/cast/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/castdemo) on Github which creates a CastPlayer as follows:

```
// set up the cast player
castPlayer = new CastPlayer(castContext);
castPlayer.addListener(this);
castPlayer.setSessionAvailabilityListener(this);
// set to a PlayerView for controls
castControlView.setPlayer(castPlayer);
```

Given your code is written against the `Player` interface you can swap a local Player with the `CastPlayer` instance.

A [blog post on Medium](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/new-cast-extension-and-demo-app-55816a50012) explains which cast pieces need to be provided by the app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972438/android-how-to-use-mediasession-extension-with-castplayer